# php codeigniter - var_dump shows array but return is null

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

so, this is weird, I have this method called treetrunk that runs up a parent child relationship and is supposed to return an array if ids as a "branchPath" - the method seems to be working just fine as a var_dump in my terminating condition shows the proper array.  However if i try to call the method the returned array is "NULL" - I really dont get it..

Model method:

```
function treeTrunk($id){//1st id in is page id
    if($id == '0'){
        var_dump($this->branchPath); //this shows perfect array 
        return $this->branchPath; //this returns null
    }
    else{
        $q = $this->getWhere(array('id'=>$id),null,null);
        array_push($this->branchPath, $q[0]['pageParent']);
        $this->treeTrunk($q[0]['pageParent']);
    }       
}
```

Calling via controller:

```
$d = $this->pages_mdl->treeTrunk('150');
var_dump($d); // <- this == NULL
```

var_dump from within method outputs "array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "148" [1]=> string(3) "146" [2]=> string(1) "0" } "

Comment: Doesn't this just return null because you're sending in '150' while the if statement is looking for '0'? Thus nothing is ever returned. What does the else portion do, call itself recursively? Does that ever get anything returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything in `else` part.

```
else{
    $q = $this->getWhere(array('id'=>$id),null,null);
    array_push($this->branchPath, $q[0]['pageParent']);
    $this->treeTrunk($q[0]['pageParent']);
}
```

should be

```
else{
    $q = $this->getWhere(array('id'=>$id),null,null);
    array_push($this->branchPath, $q[0]['pageParent']);
    return $this->treeTrunk($q[0]['pageParent']);
}
```

As posted in you question you are passing `150` to `treeTrunk()` function, so it goes to else part and gives you `null` result. The `if` part will evaluate when you pass `0` to `treeTrunk()` function.

Comment: "getWhere" gets the parent id of the id - it gets '0' when it reaches a top level page.  Returning the recursive call works though.  I'll take that.

Answer (score 0):

That is supposed to be `NULL`

```
else{
    $q = $this->getWhere(array('id'=>$id),null,null);
    array_push($this->branchPath, $q[0]['pageParent']);
    $this->treeTrunk($q[0]['pageParent']);  // You have to return this value as well
}
```

When you don't `return` that array, what else do you expect it to send back ? add a `return` statement there. When you are dealing with recursion then your last call returned the value to your second last call, but did that call return it back to the original caller? so add a `return` there

```
   return $this->treeTrunk($q[0]['pageParent']);
```

And also remove the quotation marks around integer values, not only does it look bad, it sometimes stops working as expected in PHP then.

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/dzIJeN1o)

Comment: Brilliant! ~ though I still can't wrap my head around why the var dump gave me what I was looking for but not the return... i also did not know you could return another call to the method - +1 for teaching me something new!